# How to create tabs in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, fragment

I'm creating a project that has a Navigation Drawer using fragment. 
And I wanted in the first fragment is 3 tabs appear. 
But I can not create the tabs are displayed in InicioFragment.class. How can I do?

InicioFragment.class

```
package com.menuguru;

public class InicioFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
        // getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        return rootView;
    }   
}
```

With this code the tabs always appear.

Comment: Do you want them to only be displayed when that fragment is open?

Comment: Yes so only when "this" fragment is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OnCreateView method, you need to setup your tabs programatically. Something like this:

```
    TabHost host = (TabHost) root.findViewById(R.id.tab_host);
    host.setup();

    TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab_one_container);
    spec.setIndicator("One");
    host.addTab(spec);

    spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab_two_container);
    spec.setIndicator("Two");
    host.addTab(spec);

    spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Three");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab_three_container);
    spec.setIndicator("Three");
    host.addTab(spec);


    host.setCurrentTab(0);
```

And in your xml you need to set the tabs up, too. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tab_host"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_one_container"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="One" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="Test1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_two_container"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Two" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="Test2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_three_container"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Three" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="Test3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

This should set up your 3 tabs.

Comment: not working, I want to appear only in InicioFragment

Comment: I edited the code and there should be no compile errors now. If that is still not what you were wanting, could you be a bit clearer on what you did mean please? I'm now not sure I understand

Comment: hello, I'm in doubt, how can program each tab?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question

Comment: is the following, I have implemented the Navigation Drawer that works by fragments, and wanted a fragment had 3 tabs, they appear but do not know how to program individually. it is possible to exchange contact here with you?

Comment: What do you mean by programming them individually? Do you mean dealing with what the tab contains?

Comment: Did that each had a different activity

Comment: Are you asking if each tab has a different activity? If so, then no. It is also very unreliable to change to a different activity when using a navigation drawer that implements fragments.

Comment: hello, an example of what I meant was, google play music, with drawer and tabs. is possible?

Comment: Ah ok - like the 'genres' 'home' 'top albums' 'top songs' ? The code I gave you will pretty much to that with some tweaking in the xml layout and some custom styles. Do you have the navigation drawer implemented already?

Comment: yes I have, and I have been running, but now I have another way to give PagerTitleStrip but, you know another way to get the tabs?

Comment: This should help you - http://androidhive.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/fragment-activity-in-android-coding.html

Answer (score 0):

First, create your fragment with this pattern:

```
public class TestFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    private String mContent = "???";

 public static TestFragment newInstance(String text) {
    TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(KEY_TAB_NUM, text);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    String text = getString(R.string.tab_page_num) + mContent;
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);

    return view;
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContent =  getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString(KEY_TAB_NUM) : "???";
 }
}
```

Then in your main activity declare the fragments as follows:

```
    public class VpiAbsTestActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private static final String[] TAB_TITLES = new String[] { "This", "Is", "A", "ViewPager" };

    TestFragmentAdapter mAdapter;
ViewPager mPager;
PageIndicator mIndicator;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

    mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
}

 class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {     
 private int mCount = TAB_TITLES.length;

 public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
     super(fm);
 }

 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     return TestFragment.newInstance(String.valueOf(position));
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
     return mCount;
 }

 @Override
 public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
  return TAB_TITLES[position];
 }
      }
   }
```

And finally declare in your AndroidManifest:

```
    <activity android:name="VpiAbsTestActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.VPI">
```

I've implemented in this way successfully, example taken [here](http://droidista.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/making-actionbarsherlock-and.html)